# angular-bootstrap3-datepicker calendar popup didn't update while pageloading

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, date

I am trying to implement datepicker - angular-bootstrap3-datepicker library, date picker works fine, but while assign values at page load that calendar months didn't get refreshed, still it show the current month only.

Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" data-ng-app='demo'>
<head>
<title>Angular Bootstrap3 Datepicker Demo</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/angular-bootstrap3-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div data-ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>A date in canadian english</label>
            {{date2}}
            <datepickerstefan  id="date2" data-ng-model="date2" language="en-ca" date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script src='js/fr-ca.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
<script src='js/angular-bootstrap3-datepicker.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
<script type='application/javascript'>
    var app = angular.module('demo', ['ng-bootstrap3-datepicker']);
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.date2 = "01-Jan-2015";
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Refer the screen shot: http://postimg.org/image/dso6nat17/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='application/javascript'>
    var app = angular.module('demo', ['ng-bootstrap3-datepicker']);
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.date2 = "01-Jan-2015";
        $('#date2').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: $('#date2').datepicker({}); while inclusion of this line datepicker gets empty